# Convert list containing lists of different length to a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a list, which contains lists of different length. Each of these sub-lists contains a vector of the same length.

My goal is to get a dataframe, where each of these vectors is a row.
Every solution I came across was not usable because the sub-lists don't have the same length. One example of my list below

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "CGATCTGCTTCTATT" "1" "GA/TC" "DpnI"           

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "CGATCTGCTTCTATT" "1" "/GATC" "DpnII Sau3AI MboI"

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "AGATCTGCTTCTATT" "1" "A/GATCT" "BglII"          

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "AGATCTGCTTCTATT" "1" "GA/TC" "DpnI"           

[[2]][[3]]
[1] "AGATCTGCTTCTATT" "1" "/GATC" "DpnII Sau3AI MboI"

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "CGATCCGCTTCTATT" "1" "GA/TC" "DpnI"           

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "CGATCCGCTTCTATT" "1" "/GATC" "DpnII Sau3AI MboI"

[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "AGATCCGCTTCTATT" "1" "GA/TC" "DpnI"           

[[4]][[2]]
[1] "AGATCCGCTTCTATT" "1" "/GATC" "DpnII Sau3AI MboI"

[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "CGTTCAGCTTCTATT" "1" "AG/CT" "AluI"           

[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] "CGCTCAGCTTCTATT" "1" "AG/CT" "AluI"
```

Each of these "CGCTCAGCTTCTATT" "1" "AG/CT" "AluI" should be a row in the dataframe

Comment: use `dput(head(mylist))` to include a reproducible data

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, lapply(my_list, function(x) do.call(rbind, x)))`- just change `my_lists to whatever your list is called.